# `pylint`: how do you enable errors for tabs or spaces indentation?

Tags: python, indentation, pylint, static-code-analysis, linter

I am trying to enforce some simple python formatting rules. I found `pylint` and I have been very happy. However one of the more simple formatting checks I need to enforce is: tabs-only or spaces-only indentation.

**In `pylint`, how do you enable errors or warnings for tabs or spaces indentation?**

I see that `pylint` has [`w0311` "Used when an unexpected number of indentation's tabulations or spaces has been found"](http://pylint-messages.wikidot.com/messages:w0311). But `w0311` does not enforce tabs-only or spaces-only... it still supports tabs or spaces.

I need all my python files to be only one type of indentation.

(

p.s. If you are curious how I use `pylint` to enforce my rules. I have a shell script that runs `pylint` and I use `set -o errexit` and this is hooked in with the build. So if `pylint` finds something it exits with nonzero value and causes the build to fail.

)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well what you are looking for might be this:

[mixed-indentation (W0312):
    Found indentation with %ss instead of %ss Used when there are some mixed tabs and spaces in a module.](http://pylint-messages.wikidot.com/messages:w0312)

Which is raised when:

> **Description**
>
> Used when there are some mixed tabs and spaces in a module.
>
> **Explanation**
>
> Python interprets tabs and spaces differently, so consistent
>   indentation is critical to the correct interpretation of blocks in
>   Python syntax.
>
> This warning is raised when a mix of both spaces and tabs is used in
>   indentation—or more precisely, when an indent is detected that is not
>   consistent with the indent-string option. By default, indent-string is
>   set to four spaces, the style of indentation recommended in PEP 8.

**Edit #1:**

Pylint does not have an option that I know of (and as of the moment) to "enforce" only tabs/spaces in your coding style. The above mentioned W0312 exists to warn for indentation inconsistencies on your code.

There is a trick that I use to enforce indentation: Open your project on [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) (works on the community edition also which is free) if the IDE detects inconsistencies it will warn you about them and it will give you an option to change indentation  of the current file, or keep it as it is!

Comment: if you change your answer slightly and say something about "pylint does not currently have the ability to specify tabs-only or spaces-only" then i can accept your answer. thanks a million. the mixed-indentation is good. i'll have to find something else that enforces spaces-only.

Comment: Despite the name, W0312 *actually does* enforce tabs-only or (specific-number-of-)spaces-only, defaulting to 4 spaces. It's in the second paragraph of the "Explanation" section.

Comment: True that @user2357112 !

Comment: Hey @TrevorBoydSmith I was doing a pass through my answers. Did you found this answer helpful?